# How to join 3 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I’m looking at 3 tables here with:

1 called `Users` containing a `UserID`.
`UserID` is linked by a foreign key to `UserID` in a table called `Orders`.
Within `Orders` there’s a `PassengerID` linked by a foreign key to a table called `Passengers`.

Is there anyway I can link these tables to identify the `UserID` it’s associated `OrderID` and that OrderIDs associated `passengerID`.

Comment: Are you asking how to `JOIN` two tables?

Comment: What do you mean with Idetify?

Comment: I’m pretty much asking how I can link my userID in the user table the userID in the orders tables in a join. But I want to join a third table using passengerID in orders table and passengerID  in the passenger table

Comment: I’m pretty much asking how I can link my userID in the user table the userID in the orders tables in a join. But I want to join a third table using passengerID in orders table and passengerID  in the passenger table

Answer (score 4):

This should be straightforward, probably something like this:

```
SELECT u.UserID, o.OrderID, p.PassengerID
FROM Users u
  JOIN Orders o ON u.UserID=o.UserID
  JOIN Passengers p ON o.PassengerID=p.PassengerID
WHERE ...
```

The `WHERE` condition, if you want the `WHERE` clause at all, could be e.g. `u.UserID=5` to retrieve only the results for a certain user, or `p.PassengerID=4` for a certain passenger.

A slightly shorter way of writing the same query:

```
SELECT UserID, o.OrderID, PassengerID
FROM Users u
  JOIN Orders o USING(UserID)
  JOIN Passengers p USING(PassengerID)
WHERE ...
```

Note that here the aliases `u` and `p` are not needed in the `SELECT` clause. `USING` can only be used because the columns have identical names in the two tables being joined.